# Will shell scripts called from python persist after the python script ends?

Tags: python, automation, jython, sh

As part of an automated test, I have a python script that needs to call two shell scripts that start two different servers that need to interact after the calling script ends. (It's actually a jython script, but I'm not sure that matters at this point.) What can I do to ensure that the servers stay up after the python script ends?

At this point they're called something like this:

```
def runcmd(str, sleep):
    debug('Inside runcmd, executing: ' + str)
    os.chdir("/new/dir/")
    directory = os.getcwd()
    print 'current dir: '+ directory
    os.system(str)

t = threading.Thread(
        target=runcmd,
        args=( cmd, 50,)
    )
```

Comment: Semantically, a thread's life is directly dependent on it's owner's life. So I'd really expect the thread dies with python. I'm not sure this is also a "general python" truth, though.

Comment: What are your shell scripts? are they startup scripts for daemons, or are the shell scripts themselves the servers you refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python threads will all die with Python.  Also, os.system is blocking.  But that's okay -- if the command that os.system() runs launches a new process (but not a child process), all will be fine.  On Windows, for instance, if the command begins with "start" the "start"'d process will remain after Python dies.

EDIT: `nohup` is an equivalent to `start` on Linux.  (Thanks to S. Lott).

Comment: And for unix you can use an explicit `nohup` to create a process which will linger.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system()` does not return until the process it launches has ended. Use [`subprocess`](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/subprocess.html) or [`Runtime.exec()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) if you want it in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if using subprocess.Popen would work better for you.

maybe doing something like shell=True

Answer (score 0):

Threads won't work because they are part of the process. The `system` call won't work because it blocks as your new process executes.

You will need to use something like `os.fork()` to spawn a new process and execute it in the new process. Take a look at [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for some good cookbook style solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to launch a long-running server that's independent of its parent, you need to daemonize it. Depending on your environment, there are various wrappers that can assist in this process.